# Releasing MkMapView Memory

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, mkmapview

Is there any way to release the memory taken by an MKMapView on the iPhone ?

my MkMapview seems to take around 2megs in overall memory (as seen in Instruments/Memory).
This memory is not released when the parent view controller is deallocated (strange !).
When moving the map the MkMapView takes even more memory that never gets released.
This causes crashes of my application on the old devices.

Thanks !

Comment: Please post `void dealloc` method (of not using ARC) and `@property` declaration of `MKMapView`

Comment: I tried both ARC and non-ARC versions. Here's the non arc :

    `@property (nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;
    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [mapView release];
        mapView = nil;
    
        [super dealloc];
    }`

Comment: +1 - same problem, using arc only, controller is destroyed but map keep using ~300k of memory each time...

Comment: yes, and I still didn't find any solution to this problem :(